# Run time error using Active X controller to run another Active X controller in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a macro that uses and Active X controller and calls from another Active X controller to run a SQL query. When I run the code i keep getting an error message that says `run time error 1004. Macro's may not be available in this workbook or may not be enabled.` I checked to see if macros are enabled and they are enabled on all sheets. I am using the `application.run` method to do this. Any other reason besides the fact the macros are not enabled?

Here is the code from the command button that is being called upon

### Take Note

This section of code was created by another employee. The lack of commenting does not reflect my general programming standards.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub btnClear_Click()
    Call ClearReport
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("btnClear")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("btnRunReport").ScaleWidth 1, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("btnClear").ScaleHeight 1, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft

End Sub

Public Sub btnRunReport_Click()
    Call RunReport
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("btnRunReport")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("btnRunReport").ScaleWidth 1, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("btnRunReport").ScaleHeight 1, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft


    Columns("f:g").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Rows("10:10").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With


    Columns("f:f").ColumnWidth = 10.71
    Columns("g:g").ColumnWidth = 22.86
    Range("A10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=3, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(6, 7), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("c6").Select

End Sub
```

Here is the code from the command button that is calling the other command button

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Originalworkbook As Workbook
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False









' check if the source file is open
'change this file path if customer information query is moved/changed name
Ret = Isworkbookopen("\\showdog\service\\Test\CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm")
If Ret = False Then
' if file is not open the open file
'change this file path if customer information query is moved/changed name
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("\\showdog\service\\Test\CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm")
Else
'Just make it active
 'if filename is changed then you must change the file name below to reflect the name change
 Set wkbSource = Workbooks("CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm")
 End If

' check if the destination file is open
'change this path if Service Jobs is moved/changed name
Ret = Isworkbookopen("\\showdog\service\\Test\Pulled_Info.xlsm")
If Ret = False Then
' if file is not open file
'change this path if Service Jobs is moved/changed name
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("\\showdog\service\\Test\Pulled_Info.xlsm")
Set destSheet = wkbDest.Sheets("Pulled-Info.xlsm")
  'clear contents of sheet

 destSheet.Cells.Delete

 'run Sql in Cost break down workbook
 Application.Run "'CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm'!Sheet1.btnRunReport_Click"

'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Report")

With shttocopy
'finds last row with information
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'copies cells with information regarding the customer information
'pastes those copied cells to the service jobs workbook on the customer information sheet
'resizes columns
   .Range("A10:J" & LastRow).Copy _
               destSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)


               destSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End With



'save and close file
wkbDest.Save
wkbDest.Close




Else
'destination file is open
'Just make it active
'if filename is changed then you must change the file name below to reflect the name change
 Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Pulled_Info.xlsm")
 Set destSheet = wkbDest.Sheets("Pulled_Info")
 wkbDest.Activate
 'clear contents of sheet

 destSheet.Cells.Delete

 'run Sql in Cost break down workbook

 Application.Run "'CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm'!Sheet1.btnRunReport_Click"
'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Report")
With shttocopy
'finds last row with information
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'copies cells with information regarding the customer information
'pastes those copied cells to the service jobs workbook on the customer information sheet
'resizes columns
   .Range("A10:J" & LastRow).Copy _
               destSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

               destSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


End With


shttocopy.Activate

wkbDest.Save





End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
'function to check if file is already open 
Function Isworkbookopen(filename As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim nam As String

wbname = filename
On Error Resume Next

ff = FreeFile()
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case ErrNo
Case 0: Isworkbookopen = False
Case 70: Isworkbookopen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select

End Function
```

Any other relevant code may be provided upon request

Comment: Assuming that's an activex button on a worksheet, you need to include the sheet's codename in the call: `Application.Run "'CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm'!codenamehere.btnRunReport_Click"`

Comment: I did that and I get the same result. I double checked to ensure I have macro's enabled on all workbooks and I do. Is there anything else that could cause this issue?

Comment: Is the workbook already open?

Comment: yeah it is already opened.

Comment: OK, 2 more questions: 1. Are you sure you used the sheet code name and not the tab name? 2. Did your code open the workbook?

Comment: The code does open the workbook. After inspection I was using the tab name. I changed it to the sheet code name. Now I am receiving an error that says `Error in Run_Report Description: Subscript out of range. Number: 9` then I click OK and another error message pops up that says `Run-time error 1004 Method "Run of object"_Application failed`

Comment: In the original command button there is more than one sub. Would I have to call the command button and then the sub I want to run?

Comment: No. That error means there's a problem with the code you're calling, not the way you're calling it. You'll have to post that code to get help with it.

Comment: Okay. I will post all the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rearrange where I had the `application.run` method. Code inside of the original command button `btnRunReport_click()` called upon `activesheet`. The sheet that needed to be active was not active at the point in time where the `application.run` method was being used. Posted below is the code that works as intended. Thank you to @Rory for the help in pushing me in the right direction.

```
 'Just make it active
 'if filename is changed then you must change the file name below to reflect the name change
 Set wkbSource = Workbooks("CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm")
 End If

'run Sql in Cost break down workbook
 Application.Run "'CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm'!btnRunReport_Click"
```

when compared to the code posted in the original question, you are able to see where it was originally located compared to where it is located now.